# SQL Count unique rows where a column contains two different values

Tags: sql, database, count

I have taken a good look around and not been able to find any questions that match mine. Maybe I am not using the right language when searching or whatever, but here goes.

I have an SQL table called Classes that looks something like this

```
Student_Name | Class  
--------------------  
Edgar        | Chemistry  
Allan        | Chemistry  
Burt         | Chemistry  
Edgar        | Math  
Sue          | Math  
Hamilton     | Math  
Edgar        | English  
Sue          | English  
Edgar        | German  
Ben          | German
```

I want to count how many students are taking **both** Math and German.

Assuming the following in this example:
- Student names are unique
- One student can have many classes

Logically I would use a select statement to get a result set of students who are taking Math. Then I would go through each Student_Name from the result set and check them against the table to see how many are taking German.

In this case I would expect a return of 1 as only Edgar is taking both Math and German.

Here are some of the queries I have tried so far to no avail :-(

This one was after doing some research on DISTINCT:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Student_Name) FROM Classes WHERE Class = 'Math' AND Class = 'German';
```

And this one was after finding out more about GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Student_Name FROM Classes 
    WHERE Class IN ( 'Math', 'German' ) 
    GROUP BY Student_Name
);
```

Neither of these came out quite right any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Using sqlite3 and that works perfectly! Waiting for the timer to allow me to accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) totalStudent
FROM
        (
            SELECT  student_name
            FROM    Classes
            WHERE   class IN ('Math','German')
            GROUP   BY student_name
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        ) subAlias
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2555a/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════════╗
║ TOTALSTUDENT ║
╠══════════════╣
║            1 ║
╚══════════════╝
```

Comment: Just out of interest, in terms of the query what does `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` do? Am I right in assuming it is effectively a WHERE but for when you are dealing with aggregate data?

Comment: it basically filters out the number of student in the record list in which the total record should be equal to two since there are two values in the `where` clause. here's a further demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/83213/5

Comment: Technically, if the table contained two identical rows -- i.e. ('Ross', 'German') twice -- then 'Ross' would be counted as a matching student even though he is not in 'Math'. To prevent this, there should be a UNIQUE constraint on (Student, Class) for the table.

Comment: @RossPresser good point. But even with it, you can still get the result using **HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CLASS) = 2**

Answer (score 4):

Could also do the following:

```
select count(distinct a.Student_name)
from Classes a inner join Classes b on
     a.Class = 'German' and
     b.Class = 'Math'   and
     a.Student_Name = b.Student_name;
```

This solves the problem where the table contains duplicate rows (as pointed out by a commenter to another answer)

Comment: This is good for the 2 row method, but when the number of rows grows larger, the COUNT(DISTINCT Class) is more succinct.